# Disable unique constraint on Django's ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

From [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) for [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield):

> If you don’t want multiple associations between the same instances, add a UniqueConstraint including the from and to fields. Django’s automatically generated many-to-many tables include such a constraint.

How do I disable this constraint? Is the only way to provide an explicit `through` table? Or is there a way to tell Django to not add the `UniqueConstraint` to the generated many-to-many-table?

Comment: Pretty much. You can monkey patch `django.db.models.fields.related.create_many_to_many_intermediary_model`, but that's more work then setting a through model. I don't see a supported way to dump the constraint.

Comment: @Melvyn I'd appreciate this posted as an answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

m2m tables are linked by an intermediary table which manages the relationships and has a `unique_together` constraint. This table is automatically created but you can use your own table as the doc says with the `through` argument. You can read about it [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany). In your case you need disable the `unique_together` constraint by defining your own intermediary table.

Other options are:

1. Extend the default `ManyToManyField` and override the `contribute_to_class` method.
2. Edit the default `ManyToManyField` directly as @Melvyn mentioned.

Comment: That's not the unique that is relevant. :) The `unique_together` in Meta class of the model that Django creates is the relevant part. unique at field level defaults to False. See the method I mentioned above for details. This function is called from `ManyToManyField.contribute_to_class()`.

Comment: From my question: "Is the only way to provide an explicit through table?" So it sounds like your answer is "yes, this is the only way to disable the default UniqueConstraint". Is that right?

Comment: You can also extend the default `ManyToManyField` and override the `contribute_to_class` methods. The other way is @Melvyn comment on your main post.

Comment: @Jonatan Thanks for the info. It seems to me that creating a class for the `through` kwarg is much easier than any of the other options suggested so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can monkey patch `django.db.models.fields.related.create_many_to_many_intermediary_model`, which creates the intermediary model and that's the closest you can get to it. It is called from the `contribute_to_class` method on ManyToManyField. Of course, this is more work than specifying a through model, but if you have a use case where all (or most) of your intermediaries require no constraint, then this is worth looking into.

I don't see a supported way to override just this constraint.

And yes, you can subclass ManyToManyField and set the through model there through a utility function that is identical to the above mentioned, barring the constraint and then call super(). This would evade the constraint, because contribute_to_class doesn't call the above method when a through model is already set:

```
        if not cls._meta.abstract:
            if self.remote_field.through:
                def resolve_through_model(_, model, field):
                    field.remote_field.through = model
                lazy_related_operation(resolve_through_model, cls, self.remote_field.through, field=self)
            elif not cls._meta.swapped:
                self.remote_field.through = create_many_to_many_intermediary_model(self, cls)
```

Both methods have the same caveat: you need to manually synchronize your alternate utility with Django's upon Django upgrades, all for the purpose of removing one line:
`'unique_together': (from_, to),`.

Comment: Overriding contribute_to_class is less work than editing the Django library.

Comment: Monkey patching is different from "physically patching the Django library". You route a function/method in a class not your own to something else. The `unittest.mock` library does this extensively using it's `patch` functionality.

Comment: [Bad practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch#Pitfalls) tho.

Comment: You can say the same about Django not sticking to "do one thing" mantra. The utility could have delegated to `get_intermediairy_meta_klass`, which would have default members and would accept kwargs. These "golden rules" and BCP's are there for the common case. Fortunately, the world isn't black and white just yet and still has people that ignore them when it is appropreate :)

Comment: As you say in your original comment to my question, this is a lot more work than just creating a class and specifying the `through` kwarg to `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: Yes, doesn't pay off for a one-off. But it does if it's the rule and not the exception, cause then you can just say "unique_together=False" on your subclassed ManyToManyField and have it mapped to the alternate utility.